# Doktorvater/ Doktormutter

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german

I am searching for a Doctoral Advisor in Germany. Is the official term Doktorvater/Doktormutter? It sound a bit strange to write a Professor asking if they could be my "Doktormutter". Which terms are used in German universities?

Comment: I suspect this might be field-dependent. I have heard the term "Doktorvater" being used nowadays by young academics in some social sciences, while on the other hand, in computer science, it is absolutely unusual.

Comment: My future (no formal contract yet) supervisor is female, I call her my [future] Doktormutter ... I often realize that people struggle with this word, if I use it. They understand what it expresses, but it sounds unfamiliar to the most people, while Doktorvater is more common in use. (in contrast to O. R. Mapper's comment I also heard that term used by computer scientists)

Comment: My PhD advisor (2002) is German (b 1943). Now he's retired in Vienna where he'd been a department chair. If anyone knows academically related idioms, it's him. At one of our Applebees lunches here in the USA, we were discussing how he's my "Doktorvater." [Nouns are capitalized in German.] The title is an academic equivalent to genealogical family trees. So, by extension, his Doktorvater would be my "doctorate grandfather," etc. As an organic chemist, I can trace my PhD lineage back to Liebigs, but so can millions of others. These Trees of Knowledge will continue to grow geometrically over time

Answer (score 9):

The terms *[Doktorvater](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Doktorvater)* and *[Doktormutter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Doktormutter)*, respectively, are unofficial terms for a doctoral advisor. The masculine one is occasionally used, the feminine one is rare.

Here's the definition from Duden. The bold part highlights the part that clearly states that it is used *while* writing the dissertation.

> Doktorvater/Doktormutter: Universitätsprofessor(in), der/die dem Doktoranden das Thema für die Doktorarbeit gibt [und ihn **bei der Abfassung seiner Dissertation berät**]

As already pointed out in all the other answers, *Betreuer* or the verb *betreuen* are the preferred terms.

The important thing to note is that a doctoral advisor can be called both *Betreuer* and *Doktorvater*. Once you finished your dissertation, your advisor is naturally *not* your advisor any longer. You would then refer to him as "früherer/damaliger Betreuer".
The term *Doktorvater*, however, is still valid. It could be a little confusing if you write a second dissertation, though... ;)

For more information about *Doktorvater*, please see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doktorvater).

And finally here's a quote from [zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/2013/06/Doktorvater-Doktorand-Verhaeltnis/seite-2) that once again clearly shows that *Doktorvater* is used while still writing the dissertation.

> Laut einer im Dezember 2012 erschienenen Studie des Hochschul-Informations-Systems ist jeder fünfte Doktorand mit seiner Betreuung unzufrieden. Doch viele trauen sich nicht, die Probleme offen anzusprechen, schließlich sind sie weiterhin vom Wohlwollen des Doktorvaters abhängig.

Comment: "the feminine one is rare." only because the number of female professors is rare...

Answer (score 5):

The term *Doktorvater* is indeed used, although it may be perceived as old-fashioned by some. Whether the term *Doktormutter* is used as widely and in the same way would be a different question.

However, the word *Doktorvater* is not what you are looking for, because it describes your thesis advisor **after** you have received your doctorate degree.

As the others have already noted, the word *Betreuer(in)* in mostly used. Of course it lacks the *thesis* as in *thesis advisor*, so some context is needed. One could argue whether the *betreuen* refers to the candidate or his or her work, I think the word is used in both ways.

Yet another question is whether you should write to the professor in German at all or just stick to English. The best choice will depend on the field and the person, so it is hard to judge.

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding you but "Betreuer" and "Doktorvater" or "Doktormutter", respectively, are the same. A "Doktorvater/-mutter" is defined as "Professor(in), der/die während der Erstellung der Doktorarbeit **betreut**".

Comment: @Em1, this is not how I know the word.

Comment: Hmm, indeed several sources seem to contradict what I have written.

Comment: Amongst other, the Duden, DWDS and many more. However, what particularly confused me is that highlighted word "after" which makes no sense whatsoever (or I fail to see it), but why should anyone advise you after you've finished. I mean, yes, after you've finished you start something new and someone will help you getting started and this one is most likely also called "Betreuer", but has nothing to do with a "Doktorvater" since it's not even related to your thesis. Anyways, what you need instead is someone who advises you **while** you're writing your thesis. A "Doktorvater".

Comment: @Em1: The answer corresponds exactly to the usage I am perceiving in academia. *Doktorvater* is only used after somebody has become a doctor, i.e., after the doctor has been born. Before there is nothing for the *Doktorvater* to be a father of.

Comment: However, as long as this answer claims that a "Betreuer" can't be called "Doktorvater" while I'm writing my thesis, I'm afraid I have to downvote this answer for just being incorrect.

Comment: Removed my previous two comments, since I promoted them to an answer.

Comment: @Em1, I hope you have read all relevant SE documents before casting that vote!  :)

Comment: @Em1, since the sentence including the *after* was apparently not formulated well: I wanted to express that *A ist Bs Doktorvater means* that *B* has received a doctoral degree and *A* was his thesis advisor during that time. I seem not to have made that up out of thin air, as Wrzlprmft agrees. But looking at sources, I cannot really justify this distinction between the uses of *Doktorvater* in German and *thesis advisor* in English. I will however continue to refer to my former thesis advisor as my *Doktorvater*.

Comment: Also, it seems that the word is not as old-fashioned as I thought, but rather very post-war. Was there a Latin term that was used earlier?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I think that's the exactly the point I disagree with. "A ist Bs Doktorvater" *can mean* that B has received a doctoral degree but it's also possible that B *is still writing their thesis*. You're fine with referring to your former thesis advisor as your Doktorvater, no complain about this; but I still strongly feel that the word "after" in your answer is wrong. Correct imho would be: "while writing and after receiving"

Comment: +1 that although "Betreuer/in" is the usual term here, its meaning is context dependent. A few times when I talked about my "Betreuerin" to German-speaking friends who weren't familiar with university terms, they found it pretty funny (you also "betreue" little children).

Answer (score 3):

I find *Doktorvater* and *Doktormutter* really cute. I am sure the professor would smile if you asked him/her like this. The way how we call it in German is **Betreuer / Betreuerin**, regardless of what type of work (*Betreuer der Diplomarbeit, Praktikumsbetreuer* etc.) and the verb is **betreuen**. So you could ask your professor:

> Ich möchte Sie hiermit herzlich bitten, meine Doktorarbeit/Dissertation zu betreuen.

Comment: @guidot, danke für die Berichtigung.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use a specialized term, is there? Just send a polite email asking for a professor willing to oversee your thesis (*Dissertation betreuen*). *Doktorvater* is an unofficial term anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize, *Doktorvater/Doktormutter* is an unofficial old-fashioned term, intended for more informal use (kind of a "cute" way to call your Doctoral Advisor). Students prefer to say *Betreuer/Betreuerin*. I heard that *Doktormutter* is even less used, probably because of the small number of female professors, which made the term unfamiliar to most students.

Answer (score -1):

Doktorvater (I have never heard the term Doktormutter).
It is a superficially endearing term and conjures up warm images of the 'family'. One then thinks of one's relationship to one's own family. The warmness in some cases is sustainable, but in others it is most definitely not. One then talks, as I have done, to students writing a Ph.D. at a German university about their 'doctoral dads' and the warmness can quickly turn cold to frosty. In my 15 years' experience of teaching at a German university, I can say that students prefer Betreuer/in. But Americans seem to like the older term. Probably the cuddly sentimentality of it.